# Can't echo from database to form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

So I want to echo a specific value from my database, but it doesn't wok. I'd like to echo that value into a text form something like this:

```
<h6 class="brand-before" align="center"><small>Konyhakész fa</small></h6><br>
<input type="text" name="konyha" size="18" align="center" value="<?php echo $konyha; ?>" />
```

And this is how I connect to MySQL:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "koristuzep", "***") or die("Kapcsolódás az adatbázishoz sikertelen.");
mysql_select_db("koristuzep")or die("Kapcsolódás az adatbázishoz sikertelen.");

$konyha = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $arak WHERE ID=3")
?>
```

Comment: *I cant make it to work* is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Fetch the row from the result set and display it. RTM, [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Start reading a manual and understanding that `mysql_` api is deprecated and in php7 it is __removed__

Answer (score 0):

you should fetch the results first from $konyha as given in this example

```
   <?php
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "username";
       $password = "password";
       $dbname = "myDB";

   // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 

     $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " .$row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
  } else {
echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
 ?>
```